# If the sum of two weakly convergent sequences strongly converges, do the summands strongly converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $a_n \rightharpoonup a$ and $b_n \rightharpoonup b$ weakly in $H$, a Hilbert space, and suppose that $a_n + b_n \to a+b$ strongly in $H$.

Is it true that $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$ strongly?

I don't see if it is true. I tried the usual adding and subtracting the same term and rearranging but as unsuccessful. Also tried writing $|a_n-a| = |a_n|^2 + 2(a_n, a) + |a|^2$ and tried to pass to limit, but the first term is difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is not true: Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and $\{a_n\}$ a sequence which converges to $0$ weakly but not strongly. If $b_n=-a_n$, then $b_n\to 0$ weakly and $a_n+b_n=0$, hence $a_n+b_n$ converges to $a+b=0$ strongly. But $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ do not converge strongly to $0$.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it would change if eg, $H=L^2(\Omega)$ and both sequences were non-negative?

Comment: I don't think so. Take an example like the one above, and add a positive function to both to make them non-negative.

Answer (score 1):

No this in general is not true. Consider the space of square summable sequences, with the inner product $<(a_n),(b_n)> = \sum_{n\geq 0}a_nb_n$. Consider the sequence in this space $e_i$ is the sequence $a_n$ where $a_i=1$ and $a_j=0$ for $j \neq i$. Then the sequences $e_i$ and $-e_i$ both converge weakly to $0$. And $e_i+(-e_i)$ converges strongly to $0$ (infact the sequence is constant $0$). But neither converge $e_i$ nor $-e_i$ converge strongly to $0$.